# npm rollbackFailedOptional error when install any package

Tags: node.js, npm

I have a problem when installing any `npm` packages. here is my error:

`rollbackFailedOptional: verb npm-session xxxxxxxxxxx`

for resolving this I do some stuff but I still get the same error.

I put `registry=http://registry.npmjs.org/` in .`npmrc` file in my user folder and also run following commands:

```
npm config rm proxy
npm config rm https-proxy
```

I try to solve the problem in node `8.11.1` and node `10.1.0` and my npm version is `5.6.0`.

Why this problem occurs and how can resolve that?

**Update:**
npm config list:

```
; cli configs
metrics-registry = "http://registry.npmjs.org/"
scope = ""
user-agent = "npm/5.6.0 node/v8.11.1 win32 x64"

; userconfig C:\Users\me\.npmrc
https-proxy = "https://username:password@proxy.company.com:6050/"
proxy = "http://username:password@proxy.company.com:6050/"
registry = "http://registry.npmjs.org/"

; builtin config undefined
prefix = "C:\\Users\\me\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm"

; node bin location = C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe
; cwd = C:\Users\me
; HOME = C:\Users\me
; "npm config ls -l" to show all defaults.
```

Comment: In `https-proxy`  you are using `https://` instead use `http://`

Answer (score 8):

Can you try enter this and then re run:

```
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

Answer (score 7):

I've tried almost all methods posted in various forums like stackoverflow, github-issues etc.. but nothing seemed to work. 
Here are the commands I've executed in order which I encourage you to try because it worked for many people (but not me):

- `npm config rm proxy`
- `npm config rm https-proxy`
- `npm config set https-proxy https://username:password@proxy.company.com:6050`
- `npm config set proxy http://username:password@proxy.company.com:6050`
- `npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/`

And then when trying to install the package `npm install -g express` - it failed.

However, when I tried to run `npm install npm@latest -g` it *miraculously* executed and installed fine!
Then running `npm install -g express` again worked perfectly fine too.

**TL;DR**: updating npm to the latest version solved the issue (currently 6.0.1)

Comment: I couldn't install the last version of `nmp`

Comment: Are you behind a proxy? If so can you run `npm config list` and make sure `proxy` and `https-proxy` variables are set correctly?

Comment: Yes, I update my question please see it again.
When I check proxy server in LAN setting `Address` is proxy.xxx.yy and `Port` is 8080

Comment: Again, are you behind a corporate proxy? If you can remove proxy settings that would be great. If possible, do so. If not then I believe you have the right proxy address set in your `npm config list`. Right now what I'm seeing is `"https://username:password@proxy.company.com:6050/"` which was just an example given by me. It should be substituted by YOUR proxy address. Refer my answer how to set the `proxy` and `https-proxy` variables. Also try some ways to update your npm because that could possibly solve your issue.

Comment: I think I've been answered to your question. Yes, I behind a proxy.

Comment: In that case make sure you set your `proxy` and `https-proxy` variables by following my answer and substituting YOUR proxy address ( proxy.xxx.yy:8080 ) instead of mine, and try again installing packages.
*Also try some ways to update your npm because that could possibly solve your issue.*

Comment: All thing that I have is `Address` and `Port`, How can I found username and password?

Comment: Do you require to authenticate before using the machine? If so, enter the username and password you use to gain access to the machine. In that case it would look like for example,  `https://mohammad:pass123@proxy.company.com:6050/`.
If you do not have a authentication in place then use for example `https://proxy.company.com:6050/`

Comment: `npm install npm@latest -g` and `npm update` followed by `npm install` fixed this issue for me. This problem started for me right after I updated my Mac to Catalina.

Answer (score 3):

I am installing npm package behind corporate proxy. following steps resolved the issue for me -

1. Remove http and https proxy - npm config rm proxy and npm config rm https-proxy
2. Set registry - *npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/*
3. Set http and https proxy - *npm config set proxy yourCorporateProxyAddress:port* ,
   *npm config set https-proxy yourCorporateProxyAddress:port*
4. Install package - *npm install packageName*

Comment: I don't know of any proxies I'm supposed to use at my company, but when I turned off my VPN I could install on my own network.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by setting the proxy property of config.

The most likely reason you might be facing this problem is if you are behind a proxy.

You may follow the following steps to solve the issue

Type:

```
npm config get proxy
```

If you get null. It means the proxy is not set.

Go to Internet Explorer->Tools->Internet Options-> LAN Settings
Here you would find your proxy address and port under proxy server. If you have your username and password then do the following

```
npm config set proxy http://your-username:your-password@Proxy-address:port-number
```

After this you can use npm install.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting same error in user command prompt then tried in PowerShell as an admin and it worked.

Run the following commands in Windows PowerShell as Administrator:

```
npm config set https-proxy https://username:password@proxy.company.com:6050

npm config set proxy http://username:password@proxy.company.com:6050

config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

Answer (score 1):

I had resolved this identical issue by pointing the npm to the correct proxy when using a corporate machine. **NO ADMIN REQUIRED!!!**

Here are my steps:

1. Obtain the correct proxy by following these steps [here](https://suitabletech.com/support/helpcenter/errors-full-listing/1895-locating-proxy-server-ip-address-windows#:%7E:text=To%20locate%20your%20Proxy%20Server,to%20open%20the%20Connections%20tab.)! Copy/paste the proxy address into notepad. You will use this same proxy to set both the 'proxy' and 'proxy-https' params in the next step.
2. Execute the following 2 commands in your command window by replacing <contents> below with proxy address obtained in previous step:

   - npm config set proxy http://<proxy-server-url:port>
   - npm config set https-proxy http://<proxy-server-url:port>

**NOTE**: I ommitted 'username' and 'password' fields from the 'http://<username><password>@<proxy-server-url:port>' template which according to the [source](https://medium.com/@ogbemudiatimothy/using-npm-install-behind-a-corporate-proxy-server-db150c128899) should work 9 out of 10 times, and worked perfectly for me.

3. Navigate to your project folder from the command line and execute 'npm install <package name(s)>'. The installation should be successfull.

Answer (score 1):

## first this

```
npm config rm proxy
npm config rm https-proxy
```

## then this

```
npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
```

## then Install package

```
npm install packageName
```

**PS:** be sure to check if your internet connection is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue!

Reinstalling the latest 32-bit nodejs worked for me.

Just to note, I don't have any proxy on my network. Sometimes, when I have this problem I reconnect to my wifi, which also works sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue while trying to install from Github. The issues was because of bad usage of the scripts in package.json and their hooks.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem trying to install any npm package.
Solved by adding some proxy config

Go to Users->"yourUser"-> Open .npmrc with a text editor -> add those two lines

```
https-proxy=http://username:password@proxyUrl:port/
proxy=http://username:password@proxyUrl:port
```

**Modify username and password, setting your user information.**
**Modify proxyUrl and port according to your needs**

That worked for me!