# NPM Install giving rollbackFailedOptional

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, failed-installation, npx

After trying to use the Windows Powershell (as an admin), the command prompt (as an admin) and the bash CMD; I repeatedly get the following error after trying an npm install command:

```
npm install npm@latest -g
```

is the attempted command and...

```
[...] / rollbackFailedOptional: verb npm-session xxxxxxxxxxx
```

where the 'x's represent different letter and number combinations at each attempt, is the message. I am aware that this should be the first step in the installation of a package but it remains on this message for a long time and will not change.

I am trying to use the JavaScript React library, more specifically the 'create-react-app'. The `npm install -g create-react-app` command is also causing the error.

npm version: 6.5.0

npx version: 10.2.0

node version: 10.15.0

A solution would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution:

As my device username has both my first and last names, with a space in between, npm was reaching errors because of this. So the solution was to uninstall node from the default location and reinstall it in a folder on my C:\ drive, where there were no files in the directory that have spaces in the names. I then changed the cache location into this same C:\ drive folder, and the problem was solved.

```
npm config set cache C:\NODEJS\npm-cache
```

(these folders must be created before you can set the config directory to these.)

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.npmjs.com/try-the-latest-stable-version-of-npm In this link there is the documentation for updating npm version for windows with a link to a tool developed by Microsoft to update npm (https://github.com/felixrieseberg/npm-windows-upgrade)

Comment: Even from the administrator Powershell, and following the tutorial you linked; I was unable to get past the 'rollbackFailedOptional' issue that I had before

Comment: Check if after this commands it works pls 
npm config rm proxy
npm config rm https-proxy

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50349250/9661304 Here are a list of commands that helped some people

Comment: The config proxy command worked okay, but the 'rollbackFailedOptional' issue still occurs .

Comment: Following the link you sent, I could only complete the first 2 commands as I do not know how to go about the others; I was also unable to change my npm version to 6.0.1 (their solution to the issue) as I cannot do npm installs.

Comment: No idea then, I'm sorry

Answer (score 1):

For me, I ended up having to:

1. Uninstall Node.js
2. Remove the folder "nodejs" completely from C:\Program Files (or
   wherever you decided to install node)
3. Reinstall Node.js

After that, I did not encounter `[...] / rollbackFailedOptional: verb npm-session xxxxxxxxxxx` anymore.

I'm not quite sure what the issue was but all suggestions I found on stack did not solve this problem for me. I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you are connected to any **other VPN or proxy setting**. If so try to disable it or **disconnect from it and then execute the npm command**. It worked for me. In my case, I was using the organization laptop and was connected to **external vpn network**, so i disabled the vpn and tried the command and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

In our case the hard disc of the nexus server (repository server) was just full. Maybe someone helps this. Before looking into other more complicated options.

Answer (score 0):

for my case i uninstalled the reinstelled it and used powershell insted of cmd and it worked like a charm

Answer (score 0):

**First run these commands.**

npm config rm proxy

npm config rm https-proxy

**then run this.**

npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/

check if the internet is connected

and try to run the npm command which was giving the error.